# Diff command not working logically

Tags: linux, diff

Original file contains:

```
B
RBWBW
RWRWWRBWWWBRBWRWWBWWB
```

My file contains :

```
B
RBWBW
RWRWWRBWWWBRBWRWWBWWB
```

However when i use the command **`diff original myfile`** it shows following:

```
1,3c1,3
< B
< RBWBW
< RWRWWRBWWWBRBWRWWBWWB
---
> B
> RBWBW
> RWRWWRBWWWBRBWRWWBWWB
```

When i put -w tag (**`diff original myfile -w`**) it shows no differences... but I'm absolutely sure these two files do not have whitespace/endline differences. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe DOS text? Try doing `dos2unix file1` and `dos2unix file2` to delete possible bad characters.

Comment: Yes it was this case. thanks.

Comment: You may also try `file original` and `file myfile`, to see if they are "the same kind". If they have different line endings, it will show in that they have different descriptions.

Comment: My case: I have 2 csv files which have same content. One is CRLF line ending, the other is LF line ending. View in hex e.g. `xxd`, `hexdump` or `hexyl` helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the comments, you must have some different line endings, caused because of an original file coming from a DOS system. That's why using `-w` dropped the end of the line and files matched.

To repair the file, execute:

```
dos2unix file
```

Answer (score 7):

These texts are equal.

Maybe you have extra white spaces.

try

```
diff -w -B file1.txt file2.txt
```

-w Ignore all white space.

-B Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

Answer (score 1):

Look at them in Hex format. This way you can really see if they are the same.